# Как в aiogram 3.3.0 делать расчеты по формуле (которую я задаю), из принятого числа ботом от пользователя?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, aiogram-3.x

Вот роутер, которым пытался это сделать, но выводит просто число **`2900`**, 
а надо присвоить значение переменной, которое даст пользователь, 
а после с этой переменной провести расчеты по формуле.

Помогите пожалуйста *aiogram 3.3.0*, *python 3.9*

```
@user_private_router.message(F.text.lower() == "летняя обувь")
async def summer_cmd(message: types.Message):
    msg1 = message.text.lower()
    if msg1 == 'летняя обувь':
        await message.answer_photo(photo=FSInputFile('images/poizon.jpg', filename='IK'),caption=('Введите стоимость товара в юанях (зачеркнутая цена):'))
    global count
    count = ''
    await message.answer(f'{count*13.2+(count*0.05)+2900}')
```

Comment: а в count что? Пусто? Странно, что с ошибкой не вываливается ваш код

Comment: У тебя же вместо с вопросом сразу приходит и ответ, правильно? Тебе нужно написать новый хэндлер, в который будет приходить то, что ввел пользователь после твоего вопроса. И там уже считать по формуле и возвращать ответ.